# Problem based on $f(\frac{x+y}{2})=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> Let
>   $$f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$$
>   for all real $x$ and $y$. Also, $f'(0) = -1$ and $f(0)=1$. What is then the value of $f(2)$?

I got it as $-1$ by using some algebraic manipulations (of course used derivatives). But I want more of a geometrical approach to the problem. I feel that the given equations are related to the bisection formula of a line. Is it possible to approach the problem geometrically?

Comment: Can you show your algebraic approach?

Comment: Sure.Give me some time. @AdityaAgarwal

Comment: f'(x)=$1/h[(f(2x)+f(2h))/2-f(x)] $where h->0.Using f(x)=2f(x/2)-1 we get  f'(x)=-1..integrating we get f(x)=-x+c..putting x=0 we get c=1...so f(x)=1-x..f(2)=-2 @AdityaAgarwal

Comment: Is it possible to use the definition of a derivative here? If yes, how? (I am raising this because $x$ and $y$ both are in the input of function)

Comment: C'mon be a liitle straightforward..not getting you @AdityaAgarwal...

Comment: Where do we use the definition of derivative? We derived it in the Cartesian plane. But in the 2-d Cartesian plane, x-axis is the input axis for function and y-axis is the f(x) axis. But here, we have a $y$ in the input. So is it valid here to use the definition of derivative? If yes, how?

Comment: If we put $u=\frac{x+y}{2}$, then the function becomes, $$f(u)=\frac{f(2u-y)+f(2u-x)}{2}$$

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal I think i got it...derivative=slope of line in cartesian coordinates

Comment: Yes you are right, "Derivative=Slope of tangent to a curve". And that curve, we traditionally plot in this plane. And we are not talking about partial derivatives here. So....?

Comment: Ok intuitively here's what i get...that implies that even at the midpoint of (x,f(x)) and (y,f(y)) on the curve the value equals that on the straight line joining the two points...so it implies the slope of curve equals -1 at all points and hence it is definitely a straight line..with slope -1 and y intercept 1...so just by extending it we get f(2)=-1....yahoo!!That seems so easy now!!Thanks @AdityaAgarwal

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning that this functional equation is called Jensen's equation
 - [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22jensen%27s%20equation%22), 
[Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22jensen%27s%20equation%22&tbm=bks),
[Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22jensen%27s%20equation%22).
It is known that all continuous solutions have the form $f(x)=Ax+B$ for some $A,B\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

by using partial differentiation with respect to $x$ we can say that $$ f '\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right).\frac{1}{2}=\frac{f '(x) + 0}{2} $$

now put $x=0$ and $ f'(0)=-1$       $$f '\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)\frac{1}{2}=\frac{-1}{2} $$  $$\Rightarrow f '\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)={-1}$$ this implies $f(x)$ is a linear function with slope "$-1$" for all real value of $x$ $\Rightarrow f(x)=-x+c $ further $f(0)=1 \Rightarrow c=1$ 
now $f(2)=-2+1=-1$

Answer (score 2):

We don't have to assume that $f$ is differentiable on all of ${\mathbb R}$. Consider the function $g(x):=f(x)+x-1$. Then $g(0)=g'(0)=0$, and $g$ satisfies the same functional equation as $f$. In particular $g({x\over2})={1\over 2}g(x)$ for all $x$. Choose an $x\ne0$. Then we have
$$g(x)=2^n\> g\bigl(2^{-n}x\bigr)=x\>{g(x/2^n)\over x/2^n}\to\> x g'(0)=0\qquad (n\to\infty)\ ,$$
which allows to conclude that in fact $g(x)=0$. Since $x\ne0$ was arbitrary this proves that $f(x)=1-x$ $(x\in{\mathbb R})$.

Answer (score 1):

Partial differentiation with respect to $x$ yields
$$
\frac12\,f'\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)=\frac12\,f'(x)\tag{1}
$$
Setting $x=0$ and multiplying by $2$ yields
$$
f'\left(\frac y2\right)=f'(0)\tag{2}
$$
Thus, $f'$ is a constant. Therefore, the Mean Value Theorem says
$$
f(x)=f(0)+xf'(0)\tag{3}
$$
Equation $(3)$ and the information given implies
$$
f(x)=1-x\tag{4}
$$